# Print array in a cell dynamically

Tags: excel, vba

I want to display array in a single cell and each value of array should be seperated by commas but i am not able to do that please help me.Like array contain arr(a1,a2,a3)
Cell should contain values like a1,a2,a3

```
Sub foo()
    Dim col As New Collection
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select 
    For Each a In Range("B2").Cells
        col.Add a.Value 
    Next
    Dim arr() As Variant
    arr = toArray(col)
    Range("A2").Value = arr
End Sub 

Function toArray(col As Collection)
    Dim arr() As Variant 
    ReDim arr(1 To col.Count) As Variant 
    For i = 1 To col.Count
        arr(i) = col(i) 
    Next toArray = arr
End Function
```

Comment: Dim col As New Collection
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
For Each a In Range("B2").Cells
col.Add a.Value
Next
Dim arr() As Variant
arr = toArray(col)
Range("A2").Value = arr
End Sub
Function toArray(col As Collection)
Dim arr() As Variant
ReDim arr(1 To col.Count) As Variant
For i = 1 To col.Count
arr(i) = col(i)
Next
toArray = arr
End Function

Comment: I have written the code but i m not getting how to Copy array into cell

Comment: a1,a2,a3 are the cell name which are having invalid data the array should get filled during excecution

Comment: Edit your question to add your code - format it using the `{}` button.

Comment: {Dim col As New Collection  Sheets("Sheet1").Select For Each a In Range("B2").Cells {col.Add a.Value} Next Dim arr() As Variant arr = toArray(col) Range("A2").Value = arr }End Sub {Function toArray(col As Collection) Dim arr() As Variant ReDim arr(1 To col.Count) As Variant For i = 1 To col.Count {arr(i) = col(i)} Next toArray = arr End Function}

Answer (score 0):

Adjusting your code:

```
Sub foo()
    Dim col As New Collection, a As Range
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    For Each a In Range("B2:B5").Cells
        col.Add a.Value
    Next
    Dim arr() As Variant
    arr = toArray(col)
    Range("A2").Value = Join(arr, ",")
End Sub

Function toArray(col As Collection)
    Dim arr() As Variant, i As Long
    ReDim arr(0 To col.Count - 1) As Variant
    For i = 1 To col.Count
        arr(i - 1) = col(i)
    Next
    toArray = arr
End Function
```

Comment: By adding above code Error "Invalid procedure call argument"  is coming

Comment: Use a zero-based array, not a 1-based array.

Comment: how to add cell address to array as an element

Comment: `arr(indx) = c.Address()` - but it's unclear how that relates to your question

Comment: I have no idea what that code is - looks like a whole different question. I'm done on this one.

Comment: arr(indx) = c.Address()  what is c in this line??

Comment: how to add cell address to array as an element